# Error 500 when trying to create an Event in IBM Connections using REST API

Tags: rest, atom-feed, connection

I'm trying to create an event using REST within IBM Connections 4.5, I've used the IBM Connections API documentation, but when I post the request I get an Error 500, and no error message is returned.  The Atom document I am passing is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" 
    xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
<title type="text">ST0809</title>
<content type="html"><![CDATA[ Description ]]></content>
<category term="event" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"></category>
 <snx:recurrence scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" custom="yes">
      <snx:period scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
        <snx:startDate scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">2014-06-23T08:00:00.000Z</snx:startDate>
        <snx:endDate scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">2014-06-23T09:00:00.000Z</snx:endDate>
      </snx:period>
</snx:recurrence>
</entry>
```

I am posting to the URL "/communities/calendar/atom/calendar/event?calendarUuid=" with the uuid filled in obviously.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the IBM documentation, it is missing a couple of things (the documentation doesn't mention snx:period for example).

Here's the working version, notice that allday has been added.

```
<entry 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" 
xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
<title type="text">ST0809</title>
<content type="html"><![CDATA[ Description ]]></content>
<snx:allday>0</snx:allday>
<category term="event" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"></category>
<snx:recurrence scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" custom="yes">
<snx:period scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">
<snx:startDate scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">2014-06-23T08:00:00.000Z</snx:startDate>
<snx:endDate scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">2014-06-23T09:00:00.000Z</snx:endDate>
</snx:period>
</snx:recurrence>
</entry>
```